# Plotting time series charts in Plotly with calculated confidence intervals

Tags: plotly-python

I'm using cufflinks and plotly in offline mode in Jupyter mode. I need some help in plotting time series charts with calculated confidence intervals as bollinger bands.

If i have a dataframe (df) whose index is Date (MM-YYYY) and columns A, B, 0.925_A, 0.975_A as time series. I am able to plot the time series using the code below. But I want to visualise 0.925_A and 0.975A as shaded area / bollinger bands around 'A' itself.

```py
df.iplot(mode='lines', y='A', secondary_y='B', dash=['solid','dash'])
```

I was wondering if there's any way to do it together in the iplot() function above or to overlay 2 iplots() to combined area chart and line chart in one figure?

Answer (score -1):

Check out these examples:

https://plot.ly/pandas/bollinger-bands/

https://plot.ly/~jackp/17421/plotly-candlestick-chart-in-python/#/

If you're interested for having a shaded area within the bollinger bands, you can add in the last example the property `fill`. See https://plot.ly/python/filled-area-plots/ for the filled area plots...